# Java Lambda stream into different collections

Tags: java, lambda

I have a Java lambda stream that parses a file and stores the results into a collection, based on some basic filtering.

I'm just learning lambdas so bear with me here if this is ridiculously bad.  But please feel free to point out my mistakes.

For a given file:

```
#ignored
this
is
#ignored
working
fine
```

The code:

```
List<String> matches;

Stream<String> g = Files.lines(Paths.get(givenFile));

matches = g.filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#"))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());

["this", "is", "working", "fine"]
```

Now, how would I go about collecting the ignored lines into a second list within this same stream?  Something like:

```
List<String> matches;
List<String> ignored; // to store lines that start with #

Stream<String> g = Files.lines(Paths.get(exclusionFile.toURI()));

matches = g.filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#"))
           // how can I add a condition to throw these
           // non-matching lines into the ignored collection?
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I realize it would be pretty trivial to open a new stream, alter the logic a bit, and .collect() the ignored lines easily enough.  But I don't want to have to loop through this file twice if I can do it all in one stream.

Comment: it must be something like `g.filter(..).map(t->t::toString)).collect(..toList())`

Comment: See the final example in the Oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of two streams you can use `partitioningBy` in Collector

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("#ignored", "this", "is", "#ignored", "working", "fine");
Map<Boolean, List<String>> map = strings.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.startsWith("#")));
System.out.println(map);
```

output

```
{false=[this, is, working, fine], true=[#ignored, #ignored]}
```

here I used key as `Boolean` but you can change it to a meaningful string or enum

**EDIT**

If the strings can starts with some other special characters you could use `groupingBy`

```
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("#ignored", "this", "is", "#ignored", "working", "fine", "!Someother", "*star");
    Function<String, String> classifier = s -> {
        if (s.matches("^[!@#$%^&*]{1}.*")) {
            return Character.toString(s.charAt(0));
        } else {
            return "others";
        }
    };
    Map<String, List<String>> maps = strings.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(classifier));
    System.out.println(maps);
```

Output

```
{!=[!Someother], #=[#ignored, #ignored], *=[*star], others=[this, is, working, fine]}
```

also you can nest `groupingBy` and `partitioningBy`

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you could come to a generic approach for this would be something like [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
g.peek(line -> if (line.startsWith("#")) {
   ignored.add(line);
 })
 .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#"))
// how can I add a condition to throw these
// non-matching lines into the ignored collection?
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I mention it because unlike with the partitioning `Collector` you could, at least in theory, change together however many `peek`s you want--but, as you can see, you have to duplicate logic, so it's not ideal.